# Wordpress appending URL in HTML form

Tags: php, wordpress, url

How can I stop Wordpress from appending a URL and instead go to an absolute one?

By this, I mean I have a form which posts to a php page, and in the action parameter I have
`action="www.oursite.com/feedbackpage/"`
( I have also tried just `feedbackpage/`), but Wordpress always just appends it to the current URL (so it would be `http://www.oursite.com/pagewithform/www.oursite.com/feedbackpage/`)

How do I get wordpress to redirect the user to an absolute URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you either hardcode the http:// or set it to a proper relative path (so `http://www.oursite.com/feedbackpage` or `/feedbackpage/`).

Without the http:// your link is being treated as relative so it is looking for the 'www.oursite.com' folder in the current folder 'feedbackpage'.